# Default images in gallery

Tags: php, mysql, image, gallery

I'm building app in which you can have a gallery, but if you don't have images in the right moment you can choose from default images.

The admin put from the back end images in the default_images MySQL table.

User can upload also images but in different table gallery_images MySQL table.
The user can choose also some of the default images.

This is the trick part he can choose many images on the same time from the defaults or uncheck them.

I can put the defaults also in the gallery_images which are related to the users upload images but when he uncheck some of the defaults i need to remove all users default and insert them again (because i don't know which one of them is removed).

The question is how to combine the two functionalities in one table without the need to delete and insert all of the defaults on update.

[image]

Comment: add a tag field to your table, uploaded by user / admin and other to keep a tab if the user has unchecked

Comment: i has that field but the problem is that every time those default images are submitted. All the default images which the user check i need to find are they in that table retailed to that user if not insert it, if some are unchecked i need to find which one it is and remove it if they are in the database. 

Or to have all those default images in the gallery_images relaited to all the users but this is so many repeat data....